# Container class with vector of smart pointers to abstract base class

Tags: c++, stl

I am having some problems creating my container class.

This is the behaviour that I want:

```
class AbstractBase
{
    public:
        AbstractBase() { }
        virtual std::string toString()=0;
};


class Derived : public AbstractBase
{
    public:
        Derived() { }
        std::string toString() { return "Just an example " + std::to_string( _value ); }
    private:
        int _value;
};

void Container::print()
{
    for( auto i : bunch_of_different_derived_objects_that_i_own )
        std::cout << i.toString() << std::endl;
}
```

What is the best way to create a container class that "owns" a bunch of different derived objects by only keeping pointers to the AbstractBase class?

Is it possible to make the container class own different derived objects without knowing their definition?

Using

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractBase>>
```

caused weird behaviour and

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase>>
```

was impossible to iterate.

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: `Is it possible to make the container class own different derived objects without knowing their definition?:` Absolutely, that's the essence of dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractBase>>` is exactly what you want. What was that "weired behavior" ?

Comment: @40two SO weirdness when using less/greater than characters.

Comment: what for do you use less/greater character when dealing with `vector` ?

Comment: Segmentation faults when calling the destructors of derived classes.

Comment: This is what virtual destructor is for

Comment: @Piotr S I had to edit the post because of formatting errors while describing the vector definition. It is fixed now and has nothing to do with my programming problem.

Comment: When iterating over `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase>>`, make sure the loop variable is a reference, as in `for (auto& p : myvector) {p->toString();}`. That'd work for `shared_ptr` too, and is perhaps preferable, but is not mandatory.

Comment: @PiotrS Could you elaborate?

Comment: Did you provide a **virtual destructor** in your base class ? (not in your example at least...)

Comment: @quantdev No. Please explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Declare virtual destructor**

```
class AbstractBase
{
public:
    AbstractBase() { }
    virtual ~AbstractBase() = default; // this is (defaulted) virtual destructor
    virtual std::string toString() = 0;
};

class Derived : public AbstractBase
{
public:
    Derived() { }
    virtual std::string toString() override { return "Just an example " + std::to_string( _value ); }
private:
    int _value;
};
```

**2. Store shared_ptr's in vector**

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractBase>> v = { std::make_shared<Derived>() };
```

**3. Do your stuff and not care about destructors any more.**

```
for (auto i : v)
{
    std::cout << i->toString() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Read up on virtual destructors and remembered to use make_shared.
Trying it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the construction of your `for()` loop:

```
for (auto i : bunch_of_different_derived_objects_that_i_own)
{
    i.toString();
}
```

`auto` deduces the type to be `std::shared_ptr`. You can't use the `.` operator to call a member function because that will look for member functions that belong specifically to the `std::shared_ptr` class. Use the indirection operator `->` so you can access member functions of the type pointed to:

```
i->toString();
```

---

Using `std::unique_ptr` won't work either because `auto` type deduction rules are equivalent to a function template that deduces its type by value. Binding to a parameter by value will cause either a move or copy depending on the value-category of the argument. Since the elements of the vector are lvalues, a copy will be attempted which can't be done because `std::unique_ptr`s can only be moved (hence the name *unique*).

Use a reference to prevent a copy:

```
for (auto& i : bunch_of_different_derived_objects_that_i_own)
```

---

You also need a virtual destructor for your base class. If you don't provide one only the base class subobject of your elements will be called, not the derived part too.